# Pdfsharp lost Opacity of textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, pdfsharp, xps

This is my textblock `<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Not" Opacity="0.1"/>` 
I use Pdfsharp.xps to transfer, but it lost opacity, it's solid. Pdf Image:[image: pdf], Xps Image[image: xps]
Does anyone face it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your attention. I have fixed this bug, Pdfsharp.xps lost the opacity of glyphs, add RealizeFillOpacity() for writeglyph()